# PHP not acknowledging variable unless I dump/print it

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
function calc_total($data, $total){
    $date3 = new DateTime();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($data['subscriptions']); $i++){
        $date1 = new DateTime($data['subscriptions'][$i]['StartPeriod']);
        $date2 = new DateTime($data['subscriptions'][$i]['EndPeriod']);
        $date4 = new DateTime($data['subscriptions'][$i]['NextDate']);
        $diff = intval($date1->diff($date2)->format("%a"));
        $diff2 = intval($date3->diff($date4)->format("%a"));
        if ($diff < 32 && $diff2 < 32) {
            $total = $total + floatval($data['subscriptions'][$i]['AmountExcl']);
        }
    }
    return $total;

}
```

I get the error 'Undefined index: subscriptions' when trying to execute it.
But if I add a `var_dump($data['subscriptions'])` or a `print_r($data['subscriptions'])` to it it works.
It doesn't matter if I `var_dump($data['subscriptions'])` at the top, in the for or all the way at the bottom of the function, as long as I include it it suddenly acknowledges the variable, if I don't it says it's undefined. 
Why is this and how can I fix this?

This is the structure of $data (I removed most values for privacy reasons):

```
Array
(
    [controller] => subscription
    [action] => list
    [status] => success
    [date] => 2020-03-25T00:00:02+01:00
    [totalresults] => 160
    [currentresults] => 160
    [offset] => 0
    [filters] => Array
        (
            [searchat] => ProductCode
            [searchfor] => P0001
        )

    [subscriptions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Identifier] => 
                    [Debtor] => 
                    [DebtorCode] => 
                    [CompanyName] => 
                    [Initials] => 
                    [SurName] => 
                    [ProductCode] => 
                    [Description] => 
                    [Number] => 
                    [NumberSuffix] => 
                    [PriceExcl] => 
                    [Currency] => 
                    [TaxCode] => 
                    [TaxPercentage] => 
                    [DiscountPercentage] => 
                    [Periods] => 
                    [Periodic] => 
                    [StartDate] => 2020-04-01
                    [EndDate] => 2020-04-30
                    [StartPeriod] => 2020-04-01
                    [EndPeriod] => 2020-05-01
                    [NextDate] => 2020-04-01
                    [TerminationDate] => 
                    [TerminateAfter] => 
                    [Status] => 
                    [AmountExcl] => 
                    [AmountIncl] => 
                    [Modified] => 
                )
```

Comment: Because that index does not exist before!

Comment: What does the `var_dump` show?

Comment: @Markus But if it doesn't exist, why can I var_dump it all the way at the bottom of the function and then all above code works without giving the error it doesn't exist?

Comment: Which specific line does the error refer to?

Comment: If you use an index for the first time and set a value it will be created. `var_dump()` and `print_r()` are no real functions, they are language constructs like `echo()`. So they behave a bit different.

Comment: @AbraCadaver It shows an array full of data

Comment: @El_Vanja It refers to every line containing $data['subscriptions], unless I add a var_dump() or print_r() then the error does not exist at all

Comment: @MarkusZeller The $data I pass to the function is a large multidimensional array filled with data and the it has a ['subscriptions'] in it with even more data

Comment: Is there any portion of this function you're omitting or is this the entire function code? Can you include a small sample of `var_dump($data)` from the beginning of the function?

Comment: Paste a dump of `$data`, please.

Comment: @El_Vanja This is the entire function code, here is the sample: array(9) { ["controller"]=> string(12) "subscription" ["action"]=> string(4) "list" ["status"]=> string(7) "success" ["date"]=> string(25) "2020-03-25T00:00:02+01:00" ["totalresults"]=> int(160) ["currentresults"]=> int(160) ["offset"]=> int(0) ["filters"]=> array(2) { ["searchat"]=> string(11) "ProductCode" ["searchfor"]=> string(5) "P0001" } ["subscriptions"]=> array(160) { [0]=> array(28) { ["Identifier"]=> string(4) "1018" ["Debtor"]=> string(1) "8" ["DebtorCode"]=> string(2) "11" ["CompanyName"]=> string(21)

Comment: @Markus Zeller I cant post a full dump of $data as 1, it has lots of private information from consumers and 2, its a couple million characters long

Comment: Please edit that sample into the question. And might I ask, what is this function supposed to achieve? Nothing is returned, there is no output and nothing is passed by reference. Am I missing something?

Comment: @El_Vanja I was going to make it return $total, removed it for testing, I'll readd it to the function above so it doesnt confuse people

Comment: Well, I'm at a loss. Nothing about your code or data should be causing this.